# Silverlight MVVM: where did my (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) go?

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, silverlight-4.0, event-handling, icommand

I am using commanding in my viewmodel to handle events. like for example I am handling a button click event like this:

**XAML**

```
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding mvvmButtonclick}" />

                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

**Viewmodel Code**

```
   public ICommand mvvmButtonclick
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
```

**Viewmodel Constructor code to wireup the command**

```
this.mvvmButtonclick = new ActionCommand(this.ButtonClickedEvent);
```

**Actual method in the viewmodel that gets called on button click**

```
   private void ButtonClickedEvent()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("worked!!!");
    }
```

This works. So my questions are:

- Is this the correct way?
- Is there a way I can propogate the (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) parameters into my viewmodel and should I care if its not there?
- Suppose if this were a listbox selection changed event and not a button click. How do I get the value of the selected item without the **object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e** parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may be missing the point of the separation between view and view-model that the interaction triggers are designed to provide.

The purpose of the interaction triggers is to allow the designer (typically using Blend) to invoke a command on the view model.  Which UI element and which event on the UI element might invoke such a command is the **designers** choice.

If the ViewModel though did require that a specific derivative of the `EventArgs` be provided during such a call to a command then that would tie the designers hands a little.  It would create the sort of coupling between the view and view-model that interaction triggers aspires to eliminate.

As to your final question, the way to determine the currently selected item in a list box and be notified when it changes would be to create a property on the view model that is the bound to the `SelectedItem` of the ListBox. There is no need to employee interaction triggers or commands for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2):

There are some frameworks (such as Catel), that allow the forwarding of the EventArgs. For example, see this implementation:

http://catel.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/508b404f2c57#src%2fCatel.Windows35%2fMVVM%2fCommands%2fCommand.cs

The class is compatible with both Silverlight and WPF.

If you don't want to use the EventArgs, you will need to create a SelectedObject property on the ViewModel and bind it to the SelectedItem of the listbox.

Catel includes 2 example applications (both in WPF and Silverlight) that use MVVM and the EventToCommand class to edit a selected item in a listbox. I think that is what you are looking for!